# Find XML nodes with wild card in name in Scala

Tags: xml, scala, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<data>
    <a>...</a>
    <b1>...</b1>
    <c>...</c>
    <b2>...</b2>
    <d>...</d>
    <b3>...</b2>
</data>
```

In Scala, how do I extract the nodes that start with the string "b" from the `data` node (i.e., `Elem` object)?  In this case, the desired value is a sequence of three nodes:

```
[<b1>...</b1>, <b2>...</b2>, <b3>...</b3]
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't compile:

```
val orderNodes: NodeSeq = /data/*[starts-with(name(), "b")]
```

Comment: You can look into this I think. https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.regex

Comment: Single slash before `data` means that `data` is a root node. Otherwise it should be double slash `//data...`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution for small documents is to filter the sequence of nodes with the predicate you need:

```
val data = <data>
  <a>...</a>
  <b1>...</b1>
  <c>...</c>
  <b2>...</b2>
  <d>...</d>
  <b3>...</b3>
</data>

scala> (data \ "_").filter(_.label.startsWith("b"))
res1: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq(<b1>...</b1>, <b2>...</b2>, <b3>...</b3>)
```

`elem \ label` syntax returns a sequence of nodes, that have the name exactly equal to `label`. And `elem \ "_"` is a special case of that syntax, that returns all the child elements. Then you can work with that sequence of nodes like with any normal Scala collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scala.xml.XML.EventReader, which reads the XML file tag by tag.

It has 3 cases which are starTag, text, and the endTag you can extract the data you want from the XML file.

e.g. 
//scala.io.Source

```
val source = new Source(“path to XML file”)
val eventReader=new EventReader(source)
parse(xml)
def parse ={
var isStartTag= false
var isEndTag = false
var list = mutable.List()
loop(currentNode) // tail recursive function
If(xml.hasNext){
xml.next match{

case startEvent(_,label,_,_) => //your logic
loop(currentNode)

case Text(text)=> // your logic 
loop(currentNode )

case EndEvent => // your logic
loop(currentNode.tail)

case _ => loop(currentNode.tail)}}
loop(Nil)}
```

Something like this it might have some synthetic error. But the idea is that read the your interested tag and process it.

It will also help you to real very lard file as you will load only the interested tags into the memory.

If you have Elem object then you can do like this. 
From the Elem object take the nodeSeq and do like this.

node\\ ”your parent tag” \\ ”your child tag”

And at the place of your child and parent tag you can give the regex.

Like node\\ ”abc*” \\ “b*”

If you are sure that child will be present you can use .

node\\”your parent tag”\”your child tag”

Comment: Do I really have to use pull?  I was hoping there would be some sort of XPath solution.

Comment: Actually you should use pull it gives you the convince of taking the data in which you are interested. If it’s a push based you will going to get all the data which you want and you don’t. So I think pull is much better if your xml is going to be in gbs or so @PaulReiners

Comment: There is a path solution too but that will works with XML Elem there you can search with xPath but if you do this you will have to load your whole xml into the memory so if your file is like low volume you can go for that too