# How to count elements in XML file using Scala

Tags: xml, scala

I am using assert function in scala in order to compare xml files.
My problem is that I want to be able to count number of elements for example:

```
<recording>
      <mousemove y="53" x="300" t="9031"/>
      <keydown kc="s" t="9759"/>
      <keypress cc="s" t="9759"/>
      <keyup kc="s" t="9829"/>
      <execextern streamID="18" t="9833"/>
      <keydown kc="s" t="10135"/>
      <keypress cc="s" t="10135"/>
      <keyup kc="s" t="10207"/>
      <execextern streamID="19" t="10207"/>
      <keydown kc="s" t="10934"/>
      <keypress cc="s" t="10934"/>
      <keyup kc="s" t="10989"/>
      <execextern streamID="20" t="10989"/>
      <keydown kc="s" t="11362"/>
      <keypress cc="s" t="11366"/>
</recording>
```

I want to able to count # of keydown element, keydown element, key press, etc...

Comment: Do you want to count how many times keydown and keypress tag is there in your xml ?

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar - it is an example but I would like to count how many tags appear in the XML.
keypress is an example but I would like to be able to count number of tags in any given xml .

Comment: please refer my answer and let me know if it answers your question. Also you can refer to https://dzone.com/articles/basic-xml-processing-scala

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your recording tag into a `Seq[Node]`, and count each label:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val xml = <recording>
      <mousemove y="53" x="300" t="9031"/>
      <keydown kc="s" t="9759"/>
      <keypress cc="s" t="9759"/>
      <keyup kc="s" t="9829"/>
      <execextern streamID="18" t="9833"/>
      <keydown kc="s" t="10135"/>
      <keypress cc="s" t="10135"/>
      <keyup kc="s" t="10207"/>
      <execextern streamID="19" t="10207"/>
      <keydown kc="s" t="10934"/>
      <keypress cc="s" t="10934"/>
      <keyup kc="s" t="10989"/>
      <execextern streamID="20" t="10989"/>
      <keydown kc="s" t="11362"/>
      <keypress cc="s" t="11366"/>
</recording>

// number of empty entries for whatever reason.
// Not necessary if you're not using children again after this.
val children = xml.child.filterNot(_.toString().trim.isEmpty)

val mousemoveCount = children.count(_.label == "mousemove")
val keydownCount = children.count(_.label == "keydown")
val keypressCount = children.count(_.label == "keypress")
val keyupCount = children.count(_.label == "keyup")
val execexternCount = children.count(_.label == "execextern")

println(s"number of mousemove events: $mousemoveCount")
println(s"number of keydown events: $keydownCount")
println(s"number of keypress events: $keypressCount")
println(s"number of keyup events: $keyupCount")
println(s"number of execextern events: $execexternCount")


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

number of mousemove events: 1
number of keydown events: 4
number of keypress events: 4
number of keyup events: 3
number of execextern events: 3
```

---

**EDIT**

To count all XML nodes inside `recording`, leave the `.filternot(...)` part in and use `val allCount = children.size`. IE:

```
val children = xml.child.filterNot(_.toString().trim.isEmpty)
val allCount = children.size
```

Also, to make this into a general function you can just make the child node you are searching for into a variable:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val xml = <recording>
      <mousemove y="53" x="300" t="9031"/>
      <keydown kc="s" t="9759"/>
      <keypress cc="s" t="9759"/>
      <keyup kc="s" t="9829"/>
      <execextern streamID="18" t="9833"/>
      <keydown kc="s" t="10135"/>
      <keypress cc="s" t="10135"/>
      <keyup kc="s" t="10207"/>
      <execextern streamID="19" t="10207"/>
      <keydown kc="s" t="10934"/>
      <keypress cc="s" t="10934"/>
      <keyup kc="s" t="10989"/>
      <execextern streamID="20" t="10989"/>
      <keydown kc="s" t="11362"/>
      <keypress cc="s" t="11366"/>
</recording>

val children = xml.child.filterNot(_.toString().trim.isEmpty)

def countNodes(nodeName: String): Int = children.count(_.label == nodeName)

val allCount = children.size

println(s"number of mousemove events: ${countNodes("mousemove")}")
println(s"number of keydown events: ${countNodes("keydown")}")
println(s"number of keypress events: ${countNodes("keypress")}")
println(s"number of keyup events: ${countNodes("keyup")}")
println(s"number of execextern events: ${countNodes("execextern")}")

println(s"total number of events: $allCount")


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

number of mousemove events: 1
number of keydown events: 4
number of keypress events: 4
number of keyup events: 3
number of execextern events: 3
total number of events: 15
```

---

**EDIT 2**

If you want to make this generic, I recommend that you put it in a Map by grouping by the Node's label.

For example, if you just want the Node names and sizes, something like this would do:

```
children.groupBy(_.label).map {
      case(k, v) => (k, v.size)
}
// Map(mousemove -> 1, keydown -> 4, execextern -> 3, keypress -> 4, keyup -> 3)
```

If you wanted the whole Nodes, you can just remove the `.map`:

```
import scala.xml.Node
val nodeSizeMap: Map[String, Seq[Node]] = children.groupBy(_.label)
// Map(
//   mousemove -> ArrayBuffer(<mousemove y="53" x="300" t="9031"/>),
//   keydown -> ArrayBuffer(<keydown kc="s" t="9759"/>, <keydown kc="s" t="10135"/>, <keydown kc="s" t="10934"/>, <keydown kc="s" t="11362"/>),
//   execextern -> ArrayBuffer(<execextern streamID="18" t="9833"/>, <execextern streamID="19" t="10207"/>, <execextern streamID="20" t="10989"/>),
//   keypress -> ArrayBuffer(<keypress cc="s" t="9759"/>, <keypress cc="s" t="10135"/>, <keypress cc="s" t="10934"/>, <keypress cc="s" t="11366"/>),
//   keyup -> ArrayBuffer(<keyup kc="s" t="9829"/>, <keyup kc="s" t="10207"/>, <keyup kc="s" t="10989"/>)
// )
```

In context:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val xml = <recording>
      <mousemove y="53" x="300" t="9031"/>
      <keydown kc="s" t="9759"/>
      <keypress cc="s" t="9759"/>
      <keyup kc="s" t="9829"/>
      <execextern streamID="18" t="9833"/>
      <keydown kc="s" t="10135"/>
      <keypress cc="s" t="10135"/>
      <keyup kc="s" t="10207"/>
      <execextern streamID="19" t="10207"/>
      <keydown kc="s" t="10934"/>
      <keypress cc="s" t="10934"/>
      <keyup kc="s" t="10989"/>
      <execextern streamID="20" t="10989"/>
      <keydown kc="s" t="11362"/>
      <keypress cc="s" t="11366"/>
</recording>

val children = xml.child.filterNot(_.toString().trim.isEmpty)

def countNodes(nodeName: String): Int = children.count(_.label == nodeName)

val allCount = children.size

// if you just want to print
children.groupBy(_.label).foreach {
      case (k, v) => println(s"number of $k events: ${v.size}")
}

println()

// if you want to do something with the values
val nodeSizeMap: Map[String, Int] = children.groupBy(_.label).map {
      case(k, v) => (k, v.size)
}

// ... do something with nodeSizeMap

nodeSizeMap.foreach {
      case (k, v) => println(s"number of $k events: $v")
}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

number of mousemove events: 1
number of keydown events: 4
number of execextern events: 3
number of keypress events: 4
number of keyup events: 3

number of mousemove events: 1
number of keydown events: 4
number of execextern events: 3
number of keypress events: 4
number of keyup events: 3
```

---

**EDIT 3**

To make this *even more* generic, and allow searching through nested tags, you can search by the magic XML wildcard `_`. Here's an example (excuse the silliness of the XML):

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val xml = <family>
    <mother name="julie" />
    <father name="harold" />
    <child name="billy" status="good child" />
    <child name="charlie" status="good child" />
    <child name="mandy" status="bad child" />
    <child name="nigel" status="bad child" />
    <extendedfamily>
        <uncle name="jeff" />
        <auntie name="vicky" />
        <cousin name="little boy 1" />
        <cousin name="little boy 2" />
    </extendedfamily>
</family>

val familyMap = (xml \\ "_").groupBy(_.label).map { case (k, v) => (k, v.size) }

familyMap foreach {
    case (k, v) => println(s"$k count: $v")
}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

mother count: 1
auntie count: 1
uncle count: 1
child count: 4
extendedfamily count: 1
father count: 1
cousin count: 2
family count: 1
```

Comment: I want to be able to count any number of any given xml tags , keydown is an example , But I would bump into other tags names.

Comment: @tupacshakur I've edited my answer. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. it is partial , What I meant is that for example if I will have inside my xml file 18 tags of "keypressdown" and then 20 tags of "keypressup" and I will have another tag (any general tag that may appear and we need to count number of its occurences) so I would expect the program to display me:
keypressdown 18 times
keypressup 20 times
any_general_tag 15 times
another_general_tag 17 times 
etc...

Comment: Okay, I've edited again. Is this more like what you want?

Comment: Yep, that do the trick ... I have another question if it is nested tags for example:
`<elmPath id="1" t="20011">
<path>
<element id="container" index="10" tagCode="2884"/>
<element parentid="0" index="0" tagCode="2884"/>
<element index="1" tagCode="2884"/>
<element index="0" tagCode="2884"/>
<element index="1" tagCode="2884"/>
<element index="1" tagCode="2884"/>
<element id="headerSearchForm" index="0" tagCode="2406"/>
</path>
</elmPath>`

Comment: That isn't entirely trivial and probably requires another question if I'm honest. You could work it out yourself though with the stuff in my answer if you want to give that a go.

Comment: Of course I was just wondering but yeah your answer is acceptable and do the trick ! thank you for that !

Comment: Hold up, I think I've found it. I'll edit my question (again).

Comment: @tupacshakur have a look at my most recent edit. I found a way to search through nested XML (credit to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49907899/8230810)).

Answer (score 3):

Lets say your you read your xml file in a variable

```
val xmlParam = <recording>
  <mousemove y="53" x="300" t="9031"/>
  <keydown kc="s" t="9759"/>
  <keypress cc="s" t="9759"/>
  <keyup kc="s" t="9829"/>
  <execextern streamID="18" t="9833"/>
  <keydown kc="s" t="10135"/>
  <keypress cc="s" t="10135"/>
  <keyup kc="s" t="10207"/>
  <execextern streamID="19" t="10207"/>
  <keydown kc="s" t="10934"/>
  <keypress cc="s" t="10934"/>
  <keyup kc="s" t="10989"/>
  <execextern streamID="20" t="10989"/>
  <keydown kc="s" t="11362"/>
  <keypress cc="s" t="11366"/>
</recording>
```

You can count elements of the xml file using

```
(xmlParam \\ "keydown").size
(xmlParam \\ "keypress").size
(xmlParam \\ "keyup").size
```

which will tell you the count of those elements in the file. This will give you an output as

```
res0: Int = 4
res1: Int = 4
res2: Int = 3
```

You can also refer https://dzone.com/articles/basic-xml-processing-scala for xml processing. XML support is inbuilt in scala and it is better to use the functions that scala gives us.

Comment: @tupac shakur please refer my answer and let me know if it answers your question. Also you can refer to dzone.com/articles/basic-xml-processing-scala